# Difference between downloading into a file Or stream for ZipArchive extraction

Tags: c#, webclient

I want to download a big file (2,5 GB) with .Net WebClient.

**Step 1**

Now I can download the zip file:

Persist it as **local file** with webclient.DownloadFile method

OR

Persist into a **stream** with webclient.OpenRead method

**Step 2**

.Net ZipArchive does accept a stream or a local file path.

I want to extract the .zip file and read the folders/files extracted.

What is the better approach local file/stream concerning Step 2?

Comment: What happened when you tried both of them?

Comment: I don't know about the ZipArchive type you are referring to, but you might want to check if this can process a zip archive stream in a strictly forward fashion (i.e., not trying to ever seek in the ZIP archive stream). If it cannot do that (or when in doubt), trying to process the stream provided by webclient.OpenRead may not be possible, as i guess that stream (NetworkStream?) is not seekable. In this situation i would suggest to either copy the content of the stream from webclient.OpenRead into a MemoryStream if you have enough RAM, or write into to a temp ZIP file...

Comment: I just thought about resume the download what needs a local file persistance due to network connection interruption... question answered :P